# How do I make AWS CodeDeploy to use AWS CodeCommit as a Git repo?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I cant't find any documentation about this! Every example is based on GitHub repos but how can I do this with [AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)?

Comment: I guarantee that it is in development, just give it time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any direct integration available at this time.

You'll have to checkout your repo locally and then push it to S3. The easiest way to do this is with `aws deploy push`.

Comment: Thanks! It's confusing why AWS doesn't follow the "easy way" idea to get things done.

Comment: I find it absolutely astounding that they aren't integrated (and as at November 2015, still aren't).  Fancy offering CodeCommit to manage your code, and CodeDeploy to deploy your code, but then telling users that they can use git but not their own repo !  They need to look at how well IBM bluemix does this stuff ...

Comment: I believe CodePipeline is supposed to be the bridge between the two (source -> build -> deploy). That doesn't work out of the box yet though.

Comment: FYI, CodePipeline is now integrated with CodeCommit. So you could do CodeCommit -> CodeDeploy using CodePipeline. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3693

Comment: It seems like the CodeCommit and CodePipeline integration is only enabled in us-east region. We use us-west-2 (Oregon) and we can only see s3 or github.

Comment: Nov 2018... Still not integrated

Comment: Dec 2018... Still not integrated
@RandomQuestion your link is now dead :(

Comment: July 2020... Still not integrated